# iwyu adding cxxabi.h for __forced_unwind

Tags: c++, condition-variable, iwyu

I'm running iwyu over my code base, and there are a few files where it insists I add

```cpp
#include <cxxabi.h>  // for __forced_unwind
```

I was able to ablate code and find that it seems related to `cv.wait(mu)`.

Specifically, the no predicate version.

If I remove `cv.wait(mu)`, iwyu no longer suggests `cxxabi.h`.

What is this `__forced_unwind` function, why is iwyu recommending it, and can this safely be ignored?

Minimal test case:

```cpp
// foo.cpp

#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>

void foo(std::condition_variable_any* cv, std::mutex* mu) {
  cv->wait(*mu);
}
```

```sh
src/foo.cpp should add these lines:
#include <cxxabi.h>            // for __forced_unwind

src/foo.cpp should remove these lines:

The full include-list for src/foo.cpp:
#include <cxxabi.h>            // for __forced_unwind
#include <condition_variable>  // for condition_variable_any
#include <mutex>               // for mutex
---
```

Comment: Seems like the standard header in libstdc++ has this covered by including `<cxxabi_forced.h>`: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc++-v3/include/std/condition_variable So my guess us that iwyu is just not aware of that?

Comment: @Frank Thanks for pointing that out.
I added `{ include: [ "<bits/cxxabi_forced.h>", private, "<condition_variable>", public ] },` to the imp file and that took care of it for now. Not sure whether I want to include `<condition_variable>` whenever some c++ header uses `__forced_unwind`, but I'll cross that bridge later.

If you make a top-level answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: In my case it was `<ctime>` which caused this, so I added `{ include: [ "<bits/cxxabi_forced.h>", private, "<ctime>", public ] },`